# Multiple array keys from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array of keys:

```
$keys = $array('one', 'two', 'three');
```

and this value:

```
$value = 'text';
```

and I would like to create a new array:

```
$array['one']['two']['three'] = 'text';
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You want the array to be your keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array();
$current =& $array;
$keys = $array('one', 'two', 'three');
$value = 'text';

foreach (array_slice($keys, 0, -1) as $k) {
    $current[$k] = array();
    $current = & $current[$k];
}
$current[$keys[count($keys)-1]] = $value;
```

Using a reference for `$current` allows it modify the nested arrays in place.

Comment: it doesn't work for me i have an error message : 
Fatal error: Function name must be a string on line 4 !
line targeted
$keys = $array('one', 'two', 'three');