# Convert flat array to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

Imagine having an array like this:

```
[
  'key1' => 'Label 1',
  'key2' => 'Label 2',
  'key3' => 'Label 3'
];
```

How can I convert that into a multidimensional array like this:

```
[
  'key1' => [
    'key1' => 'Label 1',
    'key2' => [
      'key2' => 'Label 2',
      'key3' => [
        'key3' => 'Label 3',
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

I thought about something with a recursive function and array_shift, but I'm not sure how to code it.

The array shall be nested as deep as there are elements.

Comment: Here's something similar, except it just creates the named keys, not the numeric ones in between: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522576/multiple-array-keys-from-array/32522780#32522780

Comment: You don't need recursion, just a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with a loop, maintaining a pointer into the output array so we can simply push values further into it:

```
$result = array();
$r = &$result;
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $r[$k] = array($k => $v);
    $r = &$r[$k];
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => Label 1
            [key2] => Array
                (
                    [key2] => Label 2
                    [key3] => Array
                        (
                            [key3] => Label 3
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/M94NV)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive solution just for fun:

```
function nest(array $flat): array
{
   // base
   if (!$flat) return [];

   // recursive
   return [key($flat) => array_merge(array_splice($flat, 0, 1), nest($flat))];
}
```

In the base case when the input is empty, you return an empty array.

For the recursive case you return a key/value pair with

- key = the first key of the input and
- value = the first element merged with the result of nesting the remaining elements