# PHP Create depth in a multidimensionnal array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I'm looking for a way to transform this code that works and gives me the expected result with 3 elements:

```
<?php
$arb = array(array("a", "b", "c"));
$arb_array = array();

foreach($arb as $a){

if(!array_key_exists($a[0], $arb_array)){
$arb_array[$a[0]] = array();
}

if(!array_key_exists($a[1], $arb_array[$a[0]])){
$arb_array[$a[0]][$a[1]]= array();
}

if(!array_key_exists($a[2], $arb_array[$a[0]][$a[1]])){
$arb_array[$a[0]][$a[1]][$a[2]]= array();
}

}
?>
```

into a dynamic one that could work regardless of the amount of elements present in $a
But i'm stuck when i have to make the depth a php array dynamic

Thank you in advance for any suggestions !

Comment: Related: [Convert flat array to multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59060386/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with references:

```
$arb = array(array("a", "b", "c"));
$arb_array = array();

$arr = &$arb_array;
foreach($arb as $a) {
    foreach($a as $key) {
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $arr))
            $arr[$key] = array();
        $arr = &$arr[$key];
    }
}

print_r($arb_array);
```